# how to pass params to a function that gets returned?

Tags: php, function, lambda, functional-programming, return

```
function callme() {
    //stuff
    return function($type = '%') use (&$data) {
        //stuff goes here
        return $data;
    };
}
```

How can I pass a param to overwrite `$type`

I just need some examples.

Comment: You mean pass a param to `callme`?

Comment: No, to the return function...To replace `%` string

Comment: Yes, but replace the `'%'` with what? With something you pass to `callme`? With something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you call `callme()` to get the function. Then you call the function and you pass a parameter:

```
$fn = callme();
$fn("whatever you want to pass");
```

Comment: That was easy...Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When I read that question I understood it as you wanted to pass what should be the default in the returned function. I though of:

```
function callme($default_type = '%') {
    //stuff
    return function($type = $default_type) use (&$data) {
        print "$type\n";
        //stuff goes here
        return $data;
    };
}
```

But that is an syntax error. Then the best way would be doing something like this:

```
function callme($default_type = '%') {
    //stuff
    return function($type = null) use (&$data, $default_type) {
        if( $type === null )
                $type = $default_type;

        print "$type\n";
        //stuff goes here
        return $data;
    };
}

$fn = callme("maybe");
$fn();                   // prints "maybe"
$fn("Carly Rae Jepsen"); // prints "Carly Rae Jepsen"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func(callme(), 'type argument here');
```